# Does Python have a pre-existing class called 'object'?

Tags: python-2.7, class, inheritance

I am learning to make classes using template codes and one of them is coded with what looks like inheritance syntax:

`class KNNLearner(object):`

What is the purpose of `(object)` here?

Answer (score 1):

In python everything is an object, an object is an object. You can also create Meta-classes to change some behavior of your objects/object to implement something.

In you case KNNLearner(object)  the (object) permits you to pass the class that you want to KNNLearner to inherit.